# Core Data never release NSData loaded from external storage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

So I use `Core Data` to store a few images. (Also the subclass is generated with latest `mogenerator`)

(And also I'm using ARC)

Yeah I know I could just keep a reference and store it on the disk, but I thought :

*"Hey they made an option so I can do just that without having to manage it myself!"*

So I tried it and it works perfectly except all the data loaded that way is **never released**.

---

[image]

[image]

---

In the initialization of the ViewController who's gonna be in charge of displaying the images I give it the usual main `NSManagedObjectContext`.

And in a method called in `viewDidAppear` I set up the `UIScrollView` with the images :

**Edit :
So it's not really a fetch request I have an `Entity1` which have one-to-many with images and I use it to get the images
I get this entity1 from the same context. I just wanted to simplify to explain better.**

```
- (void)setupScrollViewWithEntity1:(Entity1 *)entity1 {
    DDLogVerbose(@"-- %@ : SETUP SCROLL VIEW --", self);
    // I remove any previous subviews
    [self.scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    /* Here I get the imagesArray with a NSFetchRequest */ 
    //So it's not really a fetch request I have an `Entity1` which have one-to-many with images and I use it to get the images
    NSSet *imagesSet = entity1.images;


    // So I have an NSArray holding all the Image object
    for (Image *image in imagesSet) {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = image.numberValue*frame.size.width;
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        scrollView.contentSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.scrollView.frame];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image.image];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        scrollView.delegate = self;
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:scrollView];
    }
}
```

}

In `viewWillDisappear` I save the `NSManagedObjectContext` and I would expect when the controller gets dealloc'ed that all the data would too, but it stays in memory forever.

This Line somehow retains it don't know why : `imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image.image];`

I spent 3 days on it trying to use everything, `Instruments`, rechecked if I didn't keep a strong reference somewhere.

The thing is the `UIViewController` gets `dealloc`'ed that I'm sure of, I see it in `Instruments` with the `Allocation` tool but for some reason the data stays in memory forever until the app **crashes**.

---

Here's the list of the ~20 images in memory not getting dealloc'ed :

[image]

---

And here's the details for the first object :

[image]

Thank you for reading until here, I'm really desperate :(

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention it but I tagged it let me edit that

Comment: Does the managed object context survive beyond the view controller? If so is it possible you've simply got an object graph with circular references and you're failing explicitly to [re]fault your objects?

Comment: have you tried refreshObject:mergeChanges to fault the objects? also, how did you confirm that your view controller was getting deallocated?

Comment: @Tommy yes the managed object context survive it's main/default one, how exactly would I make  circular reference like that ? It might be just that be I don't get what you mean exactly.

Comment: @J2theC Yes I tried that it doesn't do anything, and I confirmed that it gets dealloc'ed by researching it's name in instrument, witnessing it showing up and leaving :p Also I put a breakpoint in the `dealloc` method and it stopped in it so dealloc was called I'm sure of it.

Comment: Where is `imagesArray` declared and when does that get deallocated?

Comment: @Clarisse Core Data likes relationships to have inverses and Core Data relationships are strong references. So they're basically always retain cycles. But if you're already doing some timely `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` then you're already covered.

Comment: It's declared and used at the exact place I put the comment, it's just that it takes a lot of lines so I thought I just simplify it. I think it gets dealloced correctly ? But no idea how to check

Comment: Also, where do you actually execute the fetch request? In the above method, or in some other object that could be retaining the images?

Comment: @Tommy well no I'm not doing that currently, I just tried it to see if it would help but it didn't, where should I put it ?

Comment: @Mike request is executed same place I put the comment

Comment: Ok i'm gonna edit and add a few things to clarify hang on a few sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried calling `reset` on the `NSManagedObjectContext` after you are done with the images? That evicts any loaded objects from the in-memory object graph. They will then need to be fetched from disk/db next time they are required.

Comment: So weird I was convinced I already tried that ! But it works thankyou very much